# Specific Flowchart in beamer

Tags: beamer, diagrams, flow-charts

I am creating a beamer presentation, and I need to summarize my work by using flowchart
I try to use word to do it and insert as .png but I'm not happy with the result, it is not clear.
So I try to do it in beamer but I failed can someone help, please..
[image]

I do my best but a lot of errors comes out.

Comment: You could try a look to https://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram

Comment: how can I use it

Comment: @user229667  please have a look at the approximation below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small variation of @js bibra answer:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                chains,
                fit,
                positioning}
\tikzset{
   arr/.style = {draw=gray!50, line width=2mm, -{Triangle[width=4mm, length=2mm]},
                 shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt},
   box/.style = {draw, fill=#1,
                 minimum height=6mm, minimum width=44mm,
                 text width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
                 align=center},
  box/.default = white,
  boxr/.style = {box=#1,rounded corners=2pt},
   FIT/.style = {box=RoyalBlue, inner sep=0pt, fit=#1, node contents={}},
every label/.append style = {box=RoyalBlue, draw=none, text=white}
        }

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hierarchy of decisions}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 9mm,
  start chain = A going below,
                        ]
% main branch
    \begin{scope}[nodes={boxr, on chain=A, join=by arr}]
\node   {}; % name: A-1
\node   {};
\node   {};
\node   {};
\node   {};
\node   {}; % name: A-6
    \end{scope}
% right branch
\coordinate[right=of A-3.north east]    (aux1);
\coordinate[right=of A-4.south east]    (aux2);

\node (rb1) [box=RoyalBlue, right=of A-5,
             label=center:test] {};
\node (rb2) [FIT=(aux1) (aux2), above=of rb1,
             label=center:{\lipsum[1][1]}];
%
\draw[arr]  (A-5) -- (rb1);
\draw[arr]  (A-4) -- (A-4 -| rb2.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

maybe this will help -- my time spent 60mins with no input code provided

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta,chains, arrows.spaced}

\tikzset{
  startstop/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=5cm, 
    minimum height=0.5cm,
    align=center, 
    draw=black, 
    fill=red!30
    },
    myarrows/.style={
        line width=0.7mm,
        draw=blue,
        ->,>=stealth,
        },
    startstopp/.style={
        rectangle, 
%       rounded corners,
        minimum width=5cm, 
        minimum height=0.9cm,
        align=center, 
        draw=black, 
        fill=blue!30
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hierarchy of decisions}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  start chain=going below,
  every join/.style={myarrows},
  node distance=0.4cm
  ]
\node (start1) [startstop,on chain,join] {User Input};
\node (start2) [startstop,on chain,join] {User Input};
\node (start3) [startstop,on chain,join] {User Input};
\node (start4) [startstop,on chain,join] {User Input};
\node (start5) [startstop,on chain,join] {User Input};
\node (start6) [startstop,on chain,join] {User Input};
\begin{scope} [start branch=testbranch going right]
    \node[startstopp,join,on chain=going right](c1){Test Child};
\end{scope} 
\node (start7) [startstop,on chain,join] {User Input};
\begin{scope} [start branch=testbranch going right]
    \node[startstopp,join,on chain=going right](c1){Test Child};
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}%
%}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I admire your enthusiasm to help beginners who seems to be lost in starting to use LaTeX, especially TikZ. Writing solution from scratch, and at this knowing that many of them just expect *do-this-instead-me* service ...  +1 for your effort!

Comment: BTW, `arrow.spaced` is old TikZ library, which is considered as deprecated. It as well `arrows` are replaced by `arrows.meta`.